# paypal IPN get buyer transaction ID

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I need the buyer transaction ID that correspond to the transaction PayPal notifies me by IPN.
I'm using

```
$_POST['txn_id']
```

but this stores the transaction ID for the seller, not the transaction ID of the buyer. At the same time the buyer hasn't access to the transaction ID of the seller.

I understand that PayPal assign two different transactions ID, but the seller needs to stores the buyer transaction ID in order to be able to communicate with the user about an specific transaction.

Anyone know how I can receive (or search for) the buyer transaction ID when PayPal send a notification to my IPN script?

I only receive the follow data:

```
Array
(
    [mc_gross] => 7.00
    [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
    [payer_id] => F6912JHUIIHA
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payment_date] => 10:14:55 Sep 11, 2011 PDT
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [first_name] => Name
    [mc_fee] => 2.08
    [notify_version] => 3.2
    [custom] => 
    [payer_status] => verified
    [business] => myemail@gmail.com
    [quantity] => 1
    [verify_sign] => 123232jh4i32u4u3h5n435i43u5455645
    [payer_email] => payermail@gmail.com
    [txn_id] => 123u4324324yuy4574
    [payment_type] => instant
    [btn_id] => 35428120
    [last_name] => lastname
    [receiver_email] => receiver@gmail.com
    [payment_fee] => 2.08
    [shipping_discount] => 0.00
    [insurance_amount] => 0.00
    [receiver_id] => OIUWDWUERWEU
    [txn_type] => web_accept
    [item_name] => Product name
    [discount] => 0.00
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [item_number] => PRODNum
    [residence_country] => SE
    [handling_amount] => 0.00
    [shipping_method] => Default
    [transaction_subject] => Product to sell
    [payment_gross] => 7.00
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [ipn_track_id] => ydedi23484rl4itm54oi
)
```

Comment: What paypal service are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the looks of the list of variables paypal sends back, there is no buyer transaction id.

Another option:

Usually when you send your order information to paypal, you can include an invoice/order number, the buyer, if needed, is able to search his history by your invoice number (the same way they would search by transaction id) if you include it when you send the info to paypal.

Comment: According to PayPal's documentation for the invoice variable: "Optional pass-through variable that **will never be presented to your customer**. Can be used to track invoice numbers". Is this really the best option?

Comment: Nevermind, just realized the Invoice ID is indeed accessible to the buyer through their confirmation email and transaction details page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GetTransactionDetails API and pass in the buyer's transaction ID.

A sample API call would be:
METHOD=GetTransactionDetails&
TRANSACTIONID=buyers transaction ID&

See also: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetTransactionDetails

Comment: hi, the buyer transaction ID is the information I want to get when PayPal send notification of the buy using IPN. What PayPal send me is the seller transaction ID.

Comment: I know. You cannot retrieve the buyer's transaction ID. The only thing you can do is use GetTransactionDetails when the buyer inquires regarding a certain transaction ID and use that to match up the buyer's transaction ID against your transaction ID.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying why this deserves a downvote? Seeing as this accomplishes everything you need, taking into account PayPal's constraints (you cannot programatically or manually get the buyer's transction ID without talking to the buyer him/herself.)

Comment: I don't downvote you.
Anyway... what I want to know is which is the Buyer transaction ID related to a Seller transaction ID.

Comment: You cannot get the buyer's transaction ID. Simple as that.

Comment: Downvoted as although the answer may be correct in what it is saying, it doesn't answer the OPs question. The accepted answer is correct in that there is no way to get the buyers transaction id (unless you ask them).