# TransactionId issue in paypal sandbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment-gateway, paypal

I am very new to Paypal IPN, and just understand some concept.

Today, while working i found something strange.

I have paid using my personal (buyer) account then i got transactionId = xxxxxxxxxx (the unique code given by sandbox)

Then i have check my IPN History from "Seller" account and i found that for the transaction i did using my buyer account, the unique key generated is different in IPN, it is something like yyyyyyyyy instead of xxxxxxx(which I got when I did transaction).

Isn't it something wrong with me or some settings needs to do for IPN.

I have set IPN url and enable it in my "Seller" account.

Can anyone please help me.

Is this something wrong with my undestanding????

Please see image for more details.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction ID for a buyer (debit) is different from the tranaction ID for a seller (credit). This is intended.

Comment: if both are different, how can i track the inquiry i.e if my customer says i had done purchase with xxxxxxx id, how can i find in my "seller" account, because that is not match anywhere in my IPN history

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419268/paypal-ipn-get-buyer-transaction-id    --- quite interesting chats, anyway fact is that both will be different